Xamarin androd Native Upgraded MAUI Project Issue
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  XALNS7028   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll'
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:line 278
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type) in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/MetadataResolver.cs:line 111
at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve() in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/TypeReference.cs:line 278
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionCache.Resolve(TypeReference typeReference) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionCache.cs:line 20
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.d__5.MoveNext() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionRocks.cs:line 36
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.IsSubclassOf(TypeDefinition type, String typeName, IMetadataResolver resolver) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionRocks.cs:line 87
at MonoDroid.Tuner.FixAbstractMethodsStep.FixAbstractMethods(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssembliesNoShrink.RunTask()
at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 25 OjtApp (net8.0-android) C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.113\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1481
I have been facing this issue for the last four months, but I haven’t found a solution. Can anyone help me with this problem?

.NET for Android is the successor to native Xamarin.Android and it is the important non-Forms foundation of MAUI. So you may follow the docs Upgrade Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, and Xamarin.Mac projects to .NET to upgrade your app.

By the way, do you use Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView and Xamarin.Android.Support.v7 NuGet?

Please Re-write your app, Android Xamarin native not directly uprgaded to MAUI App.
